# Q: Exporting GIMP script after editing a photo?

Tags: gimp, script-fu, gimpfu

I'm wondering if it is possible to interactively edit a photo in GIMP and then export a script to programmatically transform a series of images in the same way?

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I have seen plenty of attempts to write something to do this, but all failed, because there is nothing in Gimp to really support this.

If all you do is global changes (color balance, contrast, exposure, sharpening...) then the demosaicing apps typically export "recipes" that can be re-applied to other pictures (sometimes even in batch). Despite their names demosaicing apps do not work only on sensor data, the usually also accept JPEG files as input.

Most (all?) FOSS demosaicing apps are discussed (and supported by their authors) on [pixls.us](https://discuss.pixls.us/) (which has a list of apps [here](https://pixls.us/software/).